# Is it possible that poilcy created on table will not be dropped even if the table gets dropped in oracle

Tags: policies

I have Created a table and a policy on that table.
Now whenver I am dropping a table that policy gets dropped automatiocally.Is there any way if i retain the policy even though the associated table is dropped.
Or is there any way that we can recreate a policy automatically when we are recreating that table.

Can we call trigger on DDL event like Create table 
and call the policy creation procedure there.